# Encontrar um botão usando XPath Selenium

Tags: html, python, selenium-webdriver

Estou tentando encontrar um botão usando o webdriver + selenium em python, o código do botão é:

```
<button class="w-full h-14 pt-2 pb-1 px-3 bg-accent text-dark-1 rounded-full md:rounded select-none cursor-pointer md:hover:shadow-big focus:outline-none md:focus:bg-accent-2 md:focus:shadow-small ">
    <div class="font-medium">
        <div class="text-17 md:text-18 md:font-bold leading-18">Ativar</div>
        <div class="text-13 md:text-12 font-normal md:font-medium leading-normal">4 horas Minerando</div>
    </div>
</button>
```

Eu tentei:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[.//div[text()="Ativar"]]').click()
```

Mas ocorre a mensagem de erro:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[.//div[text()="Ativar"]]"}
```

Todavia na página caso eu pesquise pelo inspecionar>Crtl+F e cole

```
//button[.//div[text()="Ativar"]]
```

ele encontra o botão... se alguém puder me ajudar por favor...

Comment: Particularmente não gosto do XPATH. Uma mudança de layout na tela e vc perde sua automatização. Porque simplesmente não utilizar `driver.find_element_by_link_text('Ativar')`?

Comment: Tenta inspecionar, dentro do inspecionar elemento, no item selecionado, clique com botão direito -> copy -> copy Xpath..
Tenta dessa forma.

Comment: Quer entender como encontar o xpath de um botão ou sabe como o xpath é extraido na ferramenta do desenvolvedor nos navegadores mas tem dúvida sobre o uso na lib do python?

Answer (score 5):

Evite usar o `find_element_by_xpath`, pois qualquer modificação no *layout* da página irá quebrar seu script.

Dê preferência aos:

- find_element_by_id
- find_element_by_name
- find_element_by_class (nem sempre válido, pois elementos diferentes podem compartilhar a mesma classe)

Porém, como não tive acesso ao fonte inteiro da página, no caso específico, eu usaria o `find_element_by_link_text` conforme abaixo

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Ativar')
elem.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Se esse for o único button na pagina, você pode tentar algo assim:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(//*button[@class='font medium']descedant-or-self::div[@class='text-17 md:text-18 md:font-bold leading-18').click();
```

Se não funcionar desse jeito, eu sugiro duas modificações:

1. Tente tirar o asterisco que coloquei antes do button.
2. Substitua  o "descedant-or-self::" por uma barra simples "/"

Acredito também  que lhe sera de ajuda esse [link](https://devhints.io/xpath) para aprender alguns truques na hora de procurar por Xpath.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, acredito que você precisa esperar a página carregar e somente ao finalizar o carregamento buscar o elemento pelo XPATH. Segue o exemplo, não testei, mas deve funcionar para o que você precisa.

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions

# Sua lógica anterior

# Essa parte do código vai esperar até o botão aparecer na tela
WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(
  expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located(
    (By.XPATH, '//button[.//div[text()="Ativar"]]')
  )
)
```

Comment: E como o @Paulo Marques disse, evite usar o XPATH.